# How to change breadcrumb's title background color in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, background-color

Here is my [website](http://znerim.com). Is it possible to change the title background color using custom css code? Currently it is red. I would like to change the color to light blue for all the titles like, "TRENDING POSTS", "SEARCH ENGINE OPTIMIZATION", "SOCIAL MEDIA", "RECENT POSTS" "POPULAR", etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using a theme, I'd be very surprised if you had to write any custom CSS rules to change this. There's probably a setting in Appearance > Customise. If not, check the documentation. It might be hidden somewhere else.

---

If there isn't, open the CSS file associated with the theme (which looks like it's at `/wp-content/themes/awaken/style.css`) and search for any instance of `#fa5742`. Copy the selector (the bit before the first brace `{` ) and add it to your custom CSS rules. For each selector add:

```
the-selector-goes-here {
   background-color: #your-blue-colour;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have made changes within the CSS file itself!

Comment: @RenzJoeDavid the only problem with doing that is if you ever update the theme you'll lose all your changes. Something to be aware of.

Comment: Ohh..Okay. I will take care. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can change background color by doing changes in these classes

```
    .awt-title
    {
        background: #0056ca;
    }
.main-widget-area .widget-title
{
background: #0056ca;
}

#awt-widget > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, #awt-widget > li.active > a:focus
{
  background: #0056ca;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!